# What's the easiest way to convert Wiki markup to HTML?

Tags: html, wiki, markup

I'm building a website that requires very basic markup capabilities. I can't use any 3rd party plugins, so I just need a simple way to convert markup to HTML. I might have a total of 3 tags that I'll allow.

What is the best way to convert `==Heading==` to `<h2>Heading</h2>`, or `--bold--` to `<b>bold</b>`? Can this be done simply with Regex, or does somebody have a simple function?

I'm writing this in C#, but examples from other languages would probably work.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a simple problem, because if you're going to display things back to the user, you'll need to also sanitise the input to ensure you don't create any [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities.

That said, you could probably do something pretty simple as you describe most easily with a regular expression replacement.

For example

```
replace the pattern ==([^=]*)== with <h2>\1</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the Wiki syntax you're using as there are several different ones.  Obviously the wiki software has this functionality somewhere; if you can't find a software package that does this for you, you could start looking for the relevant code in your wiki software.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) is what you need.

> This page is a compilation of links, descriptions, and status reports of the various alternative MediaWiki parsers — that is, programs and projects, other than MediaWiki itself, which are able or intended to translate MediaWiki's text markup syntax into something else.