# Python module for wiki markup

Tags: python, wiki, markup

Is there a `Python` module for converting `wiki markup` to other languages (e.g. `HTML`)?

A similar question was asked here, [What's the easiest way to convert wiki markup to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991/whats-the-easiest-way-to-convert-wiki-markup-to-html), but no `Python` modules are mentioned.

Just curious. :) Cheers.

Comment: I am not sure of your exact application, but there is a great list [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=wiki&submit=search).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django uses the following libraries for markup:

- [Markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/)
- [Textile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/textile)
- [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html)

You can see [how they're used in Django](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/markup/templatetags/markup.py).

Comment: +1 for Markdown, which IMO should be the default markup language for everyone, everywhere and for all time.

Comment: Yet that's not answering the actual question.

Answer (score 21):

[mwlib](https://github.com/pediapress/mwlib) provides ways of converting MediaWiki formatted text into HTML, PDF, DocBook and OpenOffice formats.

Comment: That, sir, is a truly awesome piece of software, and written in Python too.  Thanks for making me aware of it. A big +1.

Comment: No windows support though, which is sad for me.

Answer (score 7):

You should look at a good parser for [Creole](http://wikicreole.org/) syntax: [creole.py](http://wiki.sheep.art.pl/Wiki%20Creole%20Parser%20in%20Python). It can convert Creole (which is "a common wiki markup language to be used across different wikis") to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

with python-creole you can convert html to creole and creole to html... So you can convert other markups to html and then to creole...

https://code.google.com/p/python-creole/

Comment: In new python-creole version, you can also convert html back in ReSt ;) (But only a subset of ReStructuredText)