# How does one parse simple inline markup (i.e. *bold*), in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, wikitext, creole

How does one implement a parser (in Python) for a subset of wikitext that modifies text, namely:

```
*bold*, /italics/, _underline_
```

I'm converting it to LaTeX, so the conversion is from:

```
Hello, *world*! Let's /go/.
```

to:

```
Hello \textbf{world}! Let's \textit{go}.
```

Though there's nothing specific about it being a conversion to LaTeX (notably except nested cases like "*bold /italics* whatami/" => "textbf{bold \textit{italics} whatami}").

I've looked at [existing markup libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154592), but they're (a) not quite the wiki language I'd like, and (b) seemingly overpowered for this problem.

I've considered reverse engineering [Creoleparser](http://creoleparser.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html), but I'd like to know what suggestions others have before I undertake that effort.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your language is small, regular expressions might be the least painful solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "Hello, *world*! Let's /go/."
>>> str = re.sub(r"\*([^\*]*)\*", r"\textbf{\1}", str)
>>> str = re.sub(r"/([^/]*)/",   r"\textit{\1}", str)
>>> str
"Hello, \textbf{world}! Let's \textit{go}."
```

Comment: +1... for example, Markdown's Python implementation is largely done with regex search-and-replace.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. --Jamie Zawinski