# Render wikitext with Python

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikitext

I need to render wikitext (pulled from the database of a mediawiki of it's relevant) and display in some other format (ultimately to be rendered as a PDF, but basically any other format will do).

I can definately hack together something that does the job but ultimately I'll be writing it as I go along, and I can see that the overhead of implementing new tags as people in my team use them will eat up a lot of my time.

Is there a project to do this?

I saw TiddlyWiki which is written in python, which I will look into borrowing their library, but in the meantime I figured there may be a project that's a bit more niche that someone knows?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

redirect [Python module for wiki markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154592/python-module-for-wiki-markup)

Comment: why downvote, i think there are good answers. I didn't mean to pick on @Richo this question has been asked before :)

Comment: Whoopsie, I searched SO for python wikitext, should have searched for python wiki I think ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Collection

Answer (score -1):

pywikipedia i have found to be best