# Process wiki markup

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I process wiki markup in a Django template?

I have CharFields with content like `([email:bob@bob.com email], [http://bob.com website])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use something that parses wiki markup. Have a look at the [markup module](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Django).

It looks pretty straightforward - include `django.contrib.markup` in the INSTALLED_APPS section of your settings.py then load markup into the template with `{% load markup %}`. After that you can use the markup tags and filters.

It look like there's lots of other options out there. Try searching 'parse wiki markup' instead of 'process wiki markup'. I came across this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154592/python-module-for-wiki-markup) you might find helpful.