# php wiki parser for trac-style formatting

Tags: php, wiki, parsing, trac

I am creating a very simple cms for my site and rather than using html, I'd like to insert content in the same kind of wiki-format that's used by the [Trac project](http://trac.edgewall.org/).

Do you know of any open-source php scripts/classes that I can grab and use for this?

Note: I am not trying to create a wiki site. Just that formatting aspect - like how this stack exchange site accepts wiki mark-up and renders it nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [doing some more research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991/whats-the-easiest-way-to-convert-wiki-markup-to-html/46017#46017), I think I've found it.

The *Forever For Now* [wiki-syntax-to-html parser](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/projects/wiki-text-to-html.php) is pretty much the same as the formatting on the Trac project.

~I have not looked at the code yet, but its pretty likely to be cool. (like Fonzie)~

Edit - I've, now, looked at the code and its beautiful and elegant and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) might work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Its exactly the kind of thing that I'm looking for, only the syntax is not ideal. If all else fails then this is a great substitute.